# laravel route to controller being called twice

Tags: php, laravel, wamp, laravel-artisan

I am still learning laravel and have created a project with v5.4.28 also tested with dev v5.5 both versions calls the controller twice thus inserting 2 records.
This only happens if I use WAMP and visit http://localhost/laravel/public/test?test=123

if i use php artisan serve and visits this
http://127.0.0.1:8000/test?test=123
it only inserts once

if i inspect using chrome and see my network tab, i see the page being called twice on wamp.

Is this normal?

edited my routes/web.php to

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('home');
});
Route::get('/test', 'testController@store');
```

and created a testController

```
class testController extends Controller
{
    public function store()
    {
        $test = new Test;
        $test ->user_id = request('test');
        $test ->save();

        //if i put a redirect here then it wont insert twice
    }
}
```

Comment: so when u get the data inserted twice how does user_if looks like ?

Comment: provide us the input form aswell

Comment: oh it looks exactly the same
id is auto increment so
id :1 , user_id :123
id :2 , user_id :123       -> second entry

There are no input. This is just for test so i use GET parameters
test?test=123   i used the test variable and set it to 123 on the URL.

then i just insert that. Everything works well with php artisan serve.
Wamp on the otherhand loads the page twice thus inserting the record twice.

Comment: anyway, i think the problem is with WAMP.
Used XAMPP and there are no problems like this.

This can be closed now

Answer (score 9):

This could also happen if you have a middleware making a double call to `next`. For instance, say you have a parent middleware's handle function as:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards){
    // Your logic here
    return $next($request);
}
```

Now, assume you have a child middleware as below:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards){
    // Note this call to the parent's next
    $resp = parent::handler($request, $next, $guards);
    // Extra logic here
    // ... and now we make another call to next
    return $next($request);
}
```

To avoid this, ensure you have a single call to `next` in your middleware's handle function.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/controller-methods-called-twice-causing-duplicate-database-entries